# How do I Monitor Health of Bot Deployed in Azure to Spot Random Downtime

Tags: azure, botframework, health-monitoring

I'm trying to track when my bot stops responding. I think it stops responding when it doesn't get any usage for a while. I'll send it a few requests sometimes and then I won't get any responses back. I can fix this by stopping and restarting the `App Service` within the Azure Portal.

I was considering creating a cronjob that sends a `POST` request to the `somebotname.azurewebsites.net/api/messages` endpoint and e-mailing me if there's no response, but I'm not sure how to get a token so that this will pass. I was also considering doing a daily publish via azure devops but I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Is there a best practice for testing if a bot is still running?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is with **Application Insights** which you can find here

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview

It's not hard to add to a project. Simply add NuGet package and initialize with the key (InstrumentationKey).

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.7.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And init like so

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

    // This code adds other services for your application.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

With appsettings.json

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "putinstrumentationkeyhere"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

For instance here is full example for .NET core

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core

In the app insights you will see all errors in real time and you can set up alerts to notify you of downtime.

If you will have production issues there is also cool feature of **snapshot debugging** to test what happened.

Comment: This is good, but the issue doesn't exactly 'show' itself like this. The site is up, but the endpoint `POST /api/messages` is unresponsive... It doesn't even show requests coming through as `500` errors, it doesn't show requests at all. I can visit the main `somebotname.azurewebsites.net` website during these downtimes so a simple availability check doesn't help. I see that there is a `Multi-step web test` which might be able to make `POST` requests, but I don't know what this request would look like to my `/api/messages` endpoint. Could I get some help?

Comment: @craigbot, like sidecus mentioned below, did you set the "Always On" option to "On" in the General settings? This option keeps the app loaded even when there's no traffic. It is required for continuous WebJobs or for WebJobs that are triggered using a CRON expression.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "Always On" setting and make sure it's set to "On".
[Azure WebSites Always On](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-web-sites-adds-always-on/)

Configuration->General Settings->Always On

Of course, you'll need to pay more in this case.

Comment: I just checked and `Always On` is set to true. This seems to be an issue with the Azure side. My bot stops getting requests completely and doesn't `spin up` when it receives this requests (even after 10 minutes) so it doesn't seem to be an `Always On` issue. It is fixed by restarting the App.